# Magento 2 : This site can’t be reached When download backup file

Tags: admin, magento2.3.4, backup

I take system backup excluding media from Magento 2 Admin. Backup file is created successfully. But when I'm going to download getting below error.

**This site can't be reached
The web page at https://example.com/index.php/admin/backup/index/downloaditime/1711689844/typ e/nomedia/key/40fdb74a8797282daed44b467d378783d0fb878ddf7328 d0095e3afafe6823a8/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**

I don't have server access. Is there any way to fix issue and download this?

Answer (score 0):

[image] dear, I have also created a backup admin side. backup is excluding media you want too.

if you get an error when you download then go to the **var** directory in the show backup folder you can download the directory or .tgz file. better understand please check my below screenshot.

[image]
[image]

your project go to **var** directory you can download.
i think that is helpfully. so please accept my answer and upvote me.

Comment: Hi. I have already written that I don't have server access.